# Endianness confusion with ARM Neon vtbx

Tags: c++, arm, simd, endianness

I have a 16 byte permutation mask `uint8_t[16]` and a 16 byte data array `uint32_t[4]`. I want to "shuffle" this data array using `vtbl` like that:

```
          0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7    8   9    A    B    C    D    E    F
  Data ||0x0,0x0,0x1,0x2|0x0,0x3,0x0,0x4||0x5,0x6, 0x7, 0x8| 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x9||

 SMask ||0x2,0x3,0x5,0x6|0x7,0x8,0x9,0xA||0xB,0xF,0x10,0x10|0x10,0x10,0x10,0x10||

Result ||0x1,0x2,0x3,0x0|0x4,0x5,0x6,0x7||0x8,0x9, 0x0, 0x0| 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0||
```

This is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <arm_neon.h>

inline uint8x16_t Shuffle(const uint8x16_t & src, const uint8x16_t & shuffle) {
  return vcombine_u8(
          vtbl2_u8(
            (const uint8x8x2_t &)src, 
            vget_low_u8(shuffle)
          ),
          vtbl2_u8(
            (const uint8x8x2_t &)src, 
          vget_high_u8(shuffle)
          )
        );
}

int main() {
   uint32_t* data32 = new uint32_t[4];
   data32[0] = 258;             // [0x00 0x00 0x01 0x02]
   data32[1] = 196612;          // [0x00 0x03 0x00 0x04]
   data32[2] = 84281096;        // [0x05 0x06 0x07 0x08]
   data32[3] = 9;               // [0x00 0x00 0x00 0x09]    
   /*load structure*/
   uint32x4_t data32Vec = vld1q_u32(data32);

   uint8_t* sMask = new uint8_t[16];
   sMask[0] = 2;
   sMask[1] = 3;
   sMask[2] = 5;
   sMask[3] = 6;
   sMask[4] = 7;
   sMask[5] = 8;
   sMask[6] = 9;
   sMask[7] = 10;
   sMask[8] = 11;
   sMask[9] = 15;
   sMask[10] = 16;
   sMask[11] = 16;
   sMask[12] = 16;
   sMask[13] = 16;
   sMask[14] = 16;
   sMask[15] = 16;
   /*load permutationmask into vector register*/
   uint8x16_t shuffleMask = vld1q_u8(sMask);

   uint8_t* comprData = new uint8_t[16];
   /*shuffle the data with the mask and store it into an uint8_t[16]*/
   vst1q_u8(comprData, Shuffle(vreinterpretq_u8_u32(data32Vec),shuffleMask));
   for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
      std::cout << (unsigned)comprData[i] << "   " ;
   }
   std::cout << std::endl;
   delete[] comprData;
   delete[] sMask;
   delete[] data32;
   return 0;
}
```

The output looks like the following:

```
0   0   0   3   0   8   7   6   5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

It should be like that:

```
1   2   3   0   4   5   6   7   8   9   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I think it has something to do with endianness, but just don't see the problem. Does anyone has a hint?

I updated the code regarding to the answer from ErmIg. The main problem was, that I mixed up vtbx and vtbl.

Sincerely

Answer (score 1):

May be it helps you (I used these functions to shuffle bytes inside vector for Arm NEON) :

```
    inline uint8x16_t Shuffle(const uint8x16_t & src, const uint8x16_t & shuffle)
    {
        return vcombine_u8(
            vtbl2_u8((const uint8x8x2_t &)src, vget_low_u8(shuffle)),
            vtbl2_u8((const uint8x8x2_t &)src, vget_high_u8(shuffle)));
    }

    inline uint8x16_t Shuffle(const uint8x16x2_t & src, const uint8x16_t & shuffle)
    {
        return vcombine_u8(
            vtbl4_u8((const uint8x8x4_t &)src, vget_low_u8(shuffle)), 
            vtbl4_u8((const uint8x8x4_t &)src, vget_high_u8(shuffle)));
    }
```

Comment: I thought vtbl2 needs a target register at first parameter? But this looks good. In fact I think I mixed up the behaviour of vtbl and vtbx. Vtbl is what I need, thus it insert ZERO if the index is out of range. I initally thought vtbx would have this behaviour :(